# A better method than readlines?

Tags: python, match, readlines

Using Python 2.5, I am reading an HTML file for three different pieces of information.  The way I am able to find information is by finding a match with *regex** and then counting a specific number of lines down from the matching line to get the actual information I'm looking for.  **The problem is I to have to re-open the site 3 times (one for each piece of info I'm looking up).  I think it's inefficient and want to be able to look up all three things opening the site only once.**  Does anyone have a better method or suggestion?

**I will learn a better way, such as BeautifulSoup, but for now, I need a quick fix*

Code:

```
def scrubdividata(ticker):
try:
    f = urllib2.urlopen('http://dividata.com/stock/%s'%(ticker))
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        if "Annual Dividend:" in line:
            s = str(lines[i+1])
            start = '>\$'
            end = '</td>'
            AnnualDiv = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
    f = urllib2.urlopen('http://dividata.com/stock/%s'%(ticker))
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        if "Last Dividend:" in line:
            s = str(lines[i+1])
            start = '>\$'
            end = '</td>'
            LastDiv = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
    f = urllib2.urlopen('http://dividata.com/stock/%s'%(ticker))
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        if "Last Ex-Dividend Date:" in line:
            s = str(lines[i+1])
            start = '>'
            end = '</td>'
            LastExDivDate = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
    divlist.append((ticker,LastDiv,AnnualDiv,LastExDivDate))
except:
    if ticker not in errorlist:
        errorlist.append(ticker)
    else:
        pass
    pass
```

Thanks,

B

I found a solution that works!  I deleted the two extraneous urlopen and readlines commands, leaving only one for the loop (before I was only deleting the urlopen commands, but leaving readlines). Here is my corrected code:

```
def scrubdividata(ticker):
try:
    f = urllib2.urlopen('http://dividata.com/stock/%s'%(ticker))
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        if "Annual Dividend:" in line:
            s = str(lines[i+1])
            start = '>\$'
            end = '</td>'
            AnnualDiv = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
    #f = urllib2.urlopen('http://dividata.com/stock/%s'%(ticker))
    #lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        if "Last Dividend:" in line:
            s = str(lines[i+1])
            start = '>\$'
            end = '</td>'
            LastDiv = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
    #f = urllib2.urlopen('http://dividata.com/stock/%s'%(ticker))
    #lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        if "Last Ex-Dividend Date:" in line:
            s = str(lines[i+1])
            start = '>'
            end = '</td>'
            LastExDivDate = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
    divlist.append((ticker,LastDiv,AnnualDiv,LastExDivDate))
    print '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'
print ticker,LastDiv,AnnualDiv,LastExDivDate
print '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'
except:
    if ticker not in errorlist:
        errorlist.append(ticker)
    else:
        pass
    pass
```

Comment: learn BeautifulSoup, that will save you a lot of a time! And you shouldn't be doing regex on HTML...

Comment: _"The problem is I to have to re-open the site 3 times"_ Why is that? Doesn't `lines` still contain all the data you need after the first time you use it? It doesn't look like its contents get erased or anything.

Comment: Actually, Kevin, your question led me to a solution...

Comment: I was having issues because I was commenting out the two extraneous urlopen commands, but it wasn't until I also commented out the two extraneous readlines commands that I was able to get this to work.  Now I am just using the urlopen command and readlines only once for all three pieces of data

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup example for reference (Python2 from memory: I only have it for Python3 here so some of the syntax may be off a bit):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

yoursite = "http://...."
with urlopen(yoursite) as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

    for node in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class':'descrip'}):
        print node.text
        print node.next_sibling.next_sibling.text
```

Outputs (for sample input 'GOOG'):

```
Last Close:
$910.68
Annual Dividend:
N/A
Pay Date:
N/A
Dividend Yield:
N/A
Ex-Dividend Date:
N/A
Years Paying:
N/A
52 Week Dividend:
$0.00
etc.
```

BeautifulSoup can be easy to use on sites that have a predictable schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
def scrubdividata(ticker):
try:
    end = '</td>'
    f = urllib2.urlopen('http://dividata.com/stock/%s'%(ticker))
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        if "Annual Dividend:" in line:
            s = str(lines[i+1])
            start = '>\$'
            AnnualDiv = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
        if "Last Dividend:" in line:
            s = str(lines[i+1])
            start = '>\$'
            LastDiv = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
        if "Last Ex-Dividend Date:" in line:
            s = str(lines[i+1])
            start = '>'
            LastExDivDate = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
    divlist.append((ticker,LastDiv,AnnualDiv,LastExDivDate))
except:
    if ticker not in errorlist:
        errorlist.append(ticker)
    else:
        pass
    pass
```

Comment: I'd do the loop with `for i, line in enumerate(lines):` rather than looping on a range and indexing.

Comment: Sorry, The above was a quick & dirty hack of the original rather than a full refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `lines` will contain the lines that you need, so there is no need to call `f.readlines()` again.  Simply reuse `lines`

Small notes: you can use `for line in lines`:

```
def scrubdividata(ticker):
  try:
    f = urllib2.urlopen('http://dividata.com/stock/%s'%(ticker))
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if "Annual Dividend:" in line:
            s = str(lines[i+1])
            start = '>\$'
            end = '</td>'
            AnnualDiv = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)

    for line in lines:
        if "Last Dividend:" in line:
            s = str(lines[i+1])
            start = '>\$'
            end = '</td>'
            LastDiv = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)

    for line in lines:
        if "Last Ex-Dividend Date:" in line:
            s = str(lines[i+1])
            start = '>'
            end = '</td>'
            LastExDivDate = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
    divlist.append((ticker,LastDiv,AnnualDiv,LastExDivDate))
  except:
    if ticker not in errorlist:
        errorlist.append(ticker)
    else:
        pass
    pass
```